# Moodle Meta Keyword

Tags: seo, moodle, meta-tags

Has anyone successfully set site keywords in their meta-tag for Moodle?

Here are a few tips that do not work for me

- Using Additional HTML under Admin>Site Setting
- Using Site Description and the Site Summary Block

Also Moodledocs is not helpful in this area - https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Search_engine_optimization

Answer (score -1):

You might have to edit the core code to do this.

There is a function called `standard_head_html()` in `/lib/outputrenderers.php`

Modify the line for `<meta name="keywords"`

Alternatively you could copy the `standard_head_html()` function into `/theme/yourthemename/renderers.php`